# firefox headless auto height screenshot

Tags: firefox, screenshot, headless

Since Firefox 57 it is possible to create screenshots headless.

But the problem is, that it creates only a screenshot from the viewport.

Is there any way to get a screenshot from the whole page without setting the height to 999999px?

Comment: What command are you trying to run? According [to the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Headless_mode), `/path/to/firefox -headless -screenshot https://developer.mozilla.com` creates a full-height screenshot with a viewport *width* of 800px (which you can override with `--window-size=1024`).

Comment: yes I'm using that command with `--window-size`. I didn't know that I can set just the width. But the default height is still way to big. I want to set it to about 300px and that it changes the height automatically until it fits